# Python Websocket 403 handshake when I try to connect

Tags: python, websocket

I'm new to websockets and am trying to play around with it. I'm trying to extract the messages on the two websites https://www.csgoroll.com/en/withdraw/csgo/p2p and https://csgoexo.com/, through chrome network tab i've identified the websocket as wss://api.csgoroll.com/graphql and wss://csgoexo.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket respectively but on both times when I try to connect I get Handshake status 403 Forbidden, and I don't know if i'm missing something or there isn't a way to connect. Here is my code:

```
import websocket
import _thread
import time
import rel

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://csgoexo.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket",
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)  # Set dispatcher to automatic reconnection
    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
    rel.dispatch()
```

Comment: Did you figure it out, having same problem with another site now

Comment: Hey bro lets compare our codes and discuss to work out a solution... you on discord?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably being recognized as a bot by the server.

Try adding some headers like `User-Agent` and `Origin` to the connection.

Use the exacts same headers you've seen on the chrome network tab as reference.

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("WEB_SOCKET_URL",
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close,
                              header={'User-Agent': '...', 'Origin': '...'})
```

It can work or not, depends on how the server does this validation or if it uses another service like cloudfare to block these requests.